# Volley: requests are being sent twice

Tags: android, android-volley

I know there are similar questions to this on this site and I have already attempted some of the recommendations solutions some of which worked for the people that previously asked this question. However, I am still getting the same data sent twice instead of once.
Here is the code:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = DialogsUtils.showProgressDialog(DirectSendActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.sending));
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                            direct_send_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean succcess = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                                if (succcess) {
                                    onSendSuccess();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    onSendFailed();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                            Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), getResources().getString(R.string.connection_problem) , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        }
                    }){
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("method",method);
                            params.put("amount", a_mount + "");
                            params.put("recipient",recipient);
                            params.put("reason",reason);
                            params.put("user_id",user_data.getString("uidkey", null));
                            Log.e(TAG, "Params: " + params.toString());
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Comment: I have no idea why the code has shown up like that.

Comment: See the edit history there were 3 spaces missing.

Comment: There's nothing in this code indicating that the request is being fired twice. Your code is very messy, maybe if you tried to order the code a bit you might find the issue yourself. Besides, you're only showing parts of your code. Where is this code being triggered from?

Comment: that code is inside a method. the method is called on android:onClick.

Answer (score 7):

Just add this before adding the request to the request queue

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                   0,
                   DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                   DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```